# Angular maintaining the variable data for every click event

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am new to angular. I have a set of rows(tr) in the table generated using *ngFor, for each table row(tr) i have a click event, when user clicks on the tr i have expand/collapse functionality to show the data in table format below the tr

Now when the user clicks on the tr, i am calling an API which provides me the data specific to the clicked tr, I am setting that data in the variable which i am using to display in the expanded tr functionality. Until now everything works fine, but when i click on the next tr the data for the previously clicked tr also gets changed and displays the data for the current tr.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let data of pageData">
<tr (click)="toggleTable(data.id)">
    <td>{{data.x}}</td>
    <td>{{data.y}}</td>
    <td>{{data.z}}</td>
    <td>{{data.a}}</td>
    <td>{{data.b}}</td>
</tr>
<tr *ngIf="data.id===currDataid && openTable">
    <td colspan="8" [ngClass]="{'p-2': true}">
      <div>
          ...
          <tr *ngFor="let idApiData of allApiData"> //problem here: id API data remains same for all parent tr when the user clicks on any parent tr
          </tr>
      </div>
    </td>
</tr>
</ng-container>
```

All i need is the tr with *ngIf should display the data specific to the id passed, but when the user clicks on multiple tr, data for all the expanded functionality gets changed and displays data with respect to variable set.

is there any way by which i can maintain the data previously clicked tr ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an expanded property to object to handle the expand collapse functionality. And you have to define a method to filter the details of the clicked row

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let data of data1">
  <tr (click)="data.expanded = !data.expanded">
    <td> {{ data.expanded ? '&ndash;' : '+'}} {{data.name}} </td>
    <td> {{data.place}} </td>
    <td> {{data.phone}} </td>
    <td> {{data.hobbies}} </td>
    <td> {{data.profession}} </td>
  </tr>
  <ng-container *ngIf="data.expanded">
    <tr *ngFor="let details of subData(data)">
      <td> {{details.datades.name}} </td>
      <td> {{details.datades.hobbies}} </td>
      <td> {{details.datades.profession}} </td>
    </tr>
  </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

Filter data using the below function or you can create a pipe for that

```
subData(data) {
  return this.data.filter(x => x.id=== data.id);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response, here my API is returning the data specific to the id. In this case subData(data) will have data only for 1 id. therefore for every tr will depict the data for the same ID. are you suggesting me maintain data in array for all the clicked tr's ?

Comment: Then u can handle this situation with the expanded attribute value